# Code for algorithm to find solution of a system

Tags: equation-solving

[image]

#### Example

[image]

I hope my English helped me to explain what I need; If it is not clear I can provide an example.

I want this code to help me find α and β faster than I find them by hand.

Comment: What do you mean by getting points from `F[x, y, z]`?. Give an example, for a value of `n`.

Comment: I did some explanation in the question with full example.

Answer (score 2):

As the information regarding the function `F` is not provided, I generated some random points for a given `n`.

```
n = 5;
pt := RandomSample[Range[7], 3];
points = Table[pt, {5}];
```

Now, generate `sets` of 2 elements and write a function which takes two points as arguments and returns solution for `α` and `β`.

```
pointsSubsetOf2 = Subsets[points, {2}];
eqnSolver[pt1_, pt2_] := Solve[{pt1.{1, α, β} == 0, pt2.{1, α, β} == 0}, {α, β}]
```

Now, get the solution for `α` and `β` for all the elements in `pointsSubsetOf2`.

```
eqnSolver @@ # & /@ pointsSubsetOf2

(* {{{α -> -2, β -> -(1/4)}}, 
    {{α -> 1, β -> -1}}, 
    {{α -> -(13/3), β -> 1/3}}, 
    {{α -> 11/2, β -> -4}}, 
    {{α -> -(27/10), β -> 1/10}}, 
    {{α -> -(1/11), β -> -(3/11)}}} *)
```

Comment: I will add F(x,y,z) because I will do the same code for every function.

Comment: Anjan, note that you can write `eqnSolver @@@ pointsSubsetOf2` (i.e. the short form for `Apply` at level {1}), instead of your expression `eqnSolver @@ # & /@ pointsSubsetOf2`.

Comment: @MarcoB Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: Thank you, I added the part of the points because if I cancel one of the points I will have less number of equations and less number of systems.